# Global behaviour for event in root model class

Tags: swift

I want to know what is best practice when triggering an event from a base model class, which will have a common outcome on all View Controllers. Say I have a shared, global variable, which can trigger an event based on different inputs. Wherever I am in my app, I wish to show a popup with the same information. With my knowledge of view controllers and swift, my only option is to implement the same code in each view controller, as I have to add that same popup to each view, depending on where I am.

Wouldn't it be nice if I could pop that popup from a global-root'ish view controller?

Is there a general coding-practice I've missed?

Comment: Why not use a common view controller base class?

Comment: How would that work? I have a root VC, which gets the calls from the model class, but I have to say currentVisibleVC.present(popupVC), don't I?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to use a navigation controller (UINavigationController) as the root controller, and then just use

```
navigationController?.topViewController
```

from any view controller added to that navigation controller.

There might appear a problem: in case if you already displayed the alert view controller, the app will try to present an alert controller on top of another one. You can keep some kind of global state, or check the type of `topViewController`.